# Bootstrap Accordion - Set to specific height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap accordion that has a list a mile long, and I would like to set the OPENED height to roughly 200px.  When I do this in the CSS, the accordion opens, but to full height, THEN sets to the 200px after it has been opened.

I attempted to style not only the collapse class, but the collapsing and collapse in classes, and all that does is have the accordion pop open with no animation.

CSS:

```
.collapse.in, .collapse{
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Where do I need to set the height so that the accordion only opens to 200px and stops the animation at 200px?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/murphy1976/c8nw2jmo/1/

Comment: added to original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind. I was styling the wrong element.
 A HEADS UP for anyone who wants to do this.  Style the WELL, the accordion will automatically take the height of it's contents. If you set the .well to a specific height, the collapse animation will ease smoothly to the desired height.

see jFiddle example to see where I placed the .well, and then modify your CSS to your taste.

Comment: sorry but your answer is not clear..if i will add specific height to .well only(no css but only height) then it will show all content..if i will add overflow-y: scroll; with height then it will work which Rene already said..

Answer (score 3):

The content height of the to-be-opened page is bigger. Bootstrap accordion is build to display all.

If you make the wrapping html element a fixed height, it works, as demonstrated in the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8nw2jmo/2/)

```
<form id="max200">

#max200 {
    height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this and also i have edit your jsfiddle example 
check that i am sure it will work fine

```
.collapse.in, .collapse{
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height:200px;
}
#instrument.collapsing{
    max-height:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap v. 4.5.0. Please check for the older versions too.

This does the job.

```
.collapse,
.collapsing {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 50vh;
}
```

.collapsing is added when the transition of the accordian starts, and removed when it finishes